# Passing std::move(obj) as an argument to a call to obj's own method

Tags: c++, move

*Context:* I have a singly-chained list of `Node`s, and calling `PruneRecursively` on its root should prune certain nodes from it, preserving the rest of the chain. Each node knows privately whether it should stay or go.

The implementation I came up with looks as follows:

```
unique_ptr<Node> Node::PruneRecursively(unique_ptr<Node> self)
{
    if (m_ChildNode)
        m_ChildNode = m_ChildNode->PruneRecursively(std::move(m_ChildNode));
    
    if (ShouldRmThis())
        return std::move(m_ChildNode);
    else
        return self;
}
```

```
if (m_RootNode)
    m_RootNode = m_RootNode->PruneRecursively(std::move(m_RootNode));
```

Look at the very last line. It looks suspect to me, because m_RootNode is move-d before a function is called on it. It works, but I think could be bad if the method `reset()`-ed the pointer, basically `delete`-ing `this`, before accessing a member.

Is it fine (if so, why), or is it a catastrophe waiting to happen?

*EDIT:* `Node::PruneRecursively` would look better if it was static, but I need virtual dispatching (`Node` is polymorphic).

Comment: Not entirely sure, if the evaluation of `operator->` for `m_ChildNode` is sequenced before the move constructor call creating the function parameter for `PruneRecursively`. If they are indeterminately sequenced, you've got a problem.

Comment: This recursive call can make the stack to grow and (for large enough structures) cause a stack overflow, and it lowers the performance. It also feels like should be a static function.

Comment: I usually advise against `unique_ptr` when building node based data structures for this very reason. Most operations become cumbersome to write and you get weird doubts popping up. The container should be the sole owner of the nodes (without leaky abstractions!) so a smart pointer for ownership semantics is moot. If you do this for "easy destruction/move", consider the cognitive price you pay on all other operations. Especially given the fact that destruction or move of node based structures is dead easy to write. Just don't leak the abstraction, and the nodes can be raw pointers.

Comment: `std::move()` is simply a cast, it does not do anything special (e.g., does not erase anything from the object or otherwise alter its state). By the time `PruneRecursively` alters it, it's already resolved. So the code is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++17 it is guaranteed that the postfix expression in a function call is evaluated before any of the expressions in the argument list. That means `operator->` on `m_RootNode` is guaranteed to be evaluated before the constructor of `self` is called. Therefore there is technically no problem.

Before C++17 there was no guarantee for this order and the constructor for `self` could be called before evaluation of the `operator->`. They were *indeterminately sequenced*. That would automatically cause undefined behavior because there would be a path in which `operator->` is guaranteed to be called on an empty `unique_ptr`.

I would however advice against relying on these new C++17 guarantees. It doesn't cost you anything really to write out e.g. a reference variable to `*m_RootNode` first and then call the function on it.

Also, with regards to the overall design, not just the evaluation of that expression, see the comments under the question.